What is the computational complexity of a second-order cone with linear matrix inequality (LMI)?
I am trying to compute the complexity of solving the following problem.
The goal is to design the parameter $(t,\textbf{x})$ where $\textbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and the formulated problem is $\min_{t,\textbf{x}} t $\text{s.t.} \Vert \textbf{A}\textbf{x}\Vert \leq t, \textbf{Q}(\textbf{x})\succeq 0 $ where $\textbf{Q}(\textbf{x})=\begin{bmatrix} \textbf{R}(\textbf{x}) & \textbf{B}(\textbf{x}) \\ \textbf{B}^H(\textbf{x}) & \textbf{I}_k \end{bmatrix}$.
$\textbf{R}$ and $\textbf{B}$ are linear mapping from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^{m \times k}$, respectively.
I know this problem is convex w.r.t $t$ and $\textbf{x}$ and confirmed this problem can be solved with the primal-dual interior point method.
Since this problem is a combination of second-order and semidefinite programming, I am confused what the complexity of solving the above problem in this case.
Can anyone advise me on what the complexity would be?
